# How to resolve "Missing the manifest.properties" in OpenNLP?

Tags: java, nlp, text-mining, opennlp

I'm trying to use OpenNLP for tokenization. I don't know what's the problem. Following is the exception:

```
opennlp.tools.util.InvalidFormatException: Missing the manifest.properties!
        at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.validateArtifactMap(BaseModel.java:209)
        at opennlp.tools.tokenize.TokenizerModel.validateArtifactMap(TokenizerModel.java:108)
        at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.(BaseModel.java:142)
        at opennlp.tools.tokenize.TokenizerModel.(TokenizerModel.java:93)
        at pk.edu.kics.JSFController.getAllTokens(JSFController.java:105)
        at pk.edu.kics.JSFController.(JSFController.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:405)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:267)
        at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:86)
        at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:175)
        at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:99)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:158)
        at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:102)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:178)
        at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:168)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:338)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:878)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1620)
        at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:848)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1613)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:380)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Where have you put the `manifest.properties` file?

Comment: I have not used manifest file, where can i find it? I'm using netbeans 6.9

Answer (score 3):

The OpenNLP model files are version-specific.  I suspect that you're trying to use a 1.4 (or earlier) model file with OpenNLP 1.5.  Make sure that you've downloaded the right model file for the version of OpenNLP you're using.